# Unable to start puppet master

Tags: puppet

Unable to start `puppetmaster`. This is new installation of puppetmaster & puppet.

I'm running following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/puppetmaster start

Starting puppetmaster: Could not prepare for execution: 
Got 6 failure(s) while initializing: 
  Could not evaluate: Could not find group puppet; 
  Could not evaluate: Could not find group puppet; 
  Could not evaluate: Could not find group puppet; 
  Could not evaluate: Could not find group puppet; 
  Could not evaluate: Could not find group puppet; 
   Could not evaluate: Could not find group puppet
                                                           [FAILED]
```

The above is noticed..

Comment: a) OS?  b) how did you install it? c) version?

Comment: - OS: Linux Centos 2.6

- How did i install: Followed the steps shown in the site http://www.craigdunn.org/2010/08/part-1-installing-puppet-2-6-1-on-centos-with-yumrpm/

-Version:2.6

Comment: This is the First time im trying to Use puppet.

Answer (score 1):

If you look through the log output, you'll see that you are missing the "puppet" group. Common for a brand new intall. If you add the group to the system you should be able to start up.

```
sudo groupadd puppet
sudo /etc/init.d/puppetmaster start
```

Comment: Thankyou. But Currently i have installed Puppet 3.0.1 on Centos 5. But Currently im facing issue to start the puppetmaster. On issuing sudo /etc/init.d/puppetmaster start [Failed] message is shown.

Comment: I understand completely. In the error message, you see this "Could not find group puppet;" Adding the group _puppet_ with `groupadd` will correct that issue.

Comment: I will try to bit more clear. Initially i have installed lower version(2.6 puppet) But later i found out that and installed latest versions Puppet 3.0.1 & ruby 1.8.7 on my Linux server. Now i'm unable to start puppetmaster. Using these commands "- sudo puppet resource group puppet ensure=present

- sudo puppet resource user puppet ensure=present gid=puppet shell='/sbin/nologin'
" Created group & user. But the same error unable to start puppet.

Comment: Are you sure that the group was actually created? Run `sudo grep puppet /etc/group` to see that the group exists. If not, add it with `groupadd` before executing the puppet commands.

Comment: On using sudo grep -r puppet /etc/group, the result was "puppet:x:10039:" hope this means group exists. IF so then what could be the reasons? for failure the of puppetmaster start up.

Comment: Hey.. Was able to start puppetmaster successfully. But in strange way. Uninstalled Ruby which uninstalled Puppet-server, puppet & facter. On re-installing  all the 4 software.. just gave a try to start it started.. On Checking the group "puppet:x:52:" this was shown.

Comment: Interesting. What else are you running on that machine? It seems odd that the group would be created with an id of 10039 then recreated (after reinstall) with an id of 52. Just curious.

Glad you got it working!

Comment: Its a Testing machine which we use for office purpose & Centos plus. Apart from that Mysql nothing much runs. I'm happy that both puppet master & puppet are running, but as this is my 1st interaction with puppet could suggest some basic programs or any site which can help me to guide how to sue puppet.

Comment: Btw what does those group number indicate 10039 or 52

Comment: Adding a group to a Linux system will generally choose the next available group id. When you get an id of 52, there's generally 51 other groups defined. Seeing that it's 10039 makes me think that something else was managing groups and started incrementing from 10000.


As far as resources go, I would go through the official documentation working through their articles: [http://docs.puppetlabs.com/](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/)